# Jasperserver export its table source not the report?

Tags: excel, jasper-reports, export, jasperserver

can we make a custom export or modify the original export function in jaspersoft server so that when we choose to export the report (e.g: export to excel), it will export all data from our select query we use in reports not the reports itself?

Comment: `it will export all data from our select query we use in reports not the reports itself` - What do you mean?

Comment: what i mean is it will export only the result of select query we used,without report template